# WinSCP .NET assembly directory list timeout

Tags: .net, winscp, winscp-net

When there are many files in the remote directory often have session timeout problem, what's the default session time and if increase will be any side effects?

```
var allFiles = session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(folderIn, null, EnumerationOptions.None);
```

Part of the error logs:

```
Timeout waiting for WinSCP to respond    
    at WinSCP.Session.CheckForTimeout(String additional)     
    at WinSCP.PatientFileStream.Wait(Int32& interval)     
    at WinSCP.PatientFileStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)     
    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText()
    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
    at WinSCP.SessionLogReader.DoRead()
    at WinSCP.SessionLogReader.Read(LogReadFlags flags)
    at WinSCP.ElementLogReader.Read(LogReadFlags flags)
    at WinSCP.SessionElementLogReader.Read(LogReadFlags flags)
    at WinSCP.ElementLogReader.Read(LogReadFlags flags)
    at WinSCP.CustomLogReader.TryWaitForNonEmptyElement(String localName, LogReadFlags flags)
    at WinSCP.CustomLogReader.WaitForNonEmptyElement(String localName, LogReadFlags flags)
    at WinSCP.Session.ListDirectory(String path)
    at WinSCP.Session.<DoEnumerateRemoteFiles>d__86.MoveNext()
```

WinSCP .NET assembly version 6.1.2

And any difference between the following two:

1. setup the timeout in SessionOptions and use it when open the session

```
var sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{ Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0) };
```

or 2) open the session then set the timeout value?

```
session.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

As *documented*, the default value of `Session.Timeout` is *one minute*:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session#timeout